# can't enable logging of spring framework

Tags: spring, logging, log4j, slf4j, apache-commons-logging

I want to configure the logging in Spring framework and Spring Security, and followed this http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-not-using-commons-logging

but when I load the Tomcat I got this problem:

> GRAVE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/RH-Explore]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/RH-Explore]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     ... 6 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/core/io/Resource  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:892)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5412)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
              <exclusions>
                 <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
              </exclusions>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
              <exclusions>
                 <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
              </exclusions>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                 <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.8</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.8</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.8</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.14</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem !!

first of all, this error:

> GRAVE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/RH-Explore]]

is problem of deployment, so I did a clean for the project and then i got this error :

> Grave: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé
>   (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener)
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V

this error is a problem of compatibilities of the `SLF4J`, so I changed the version from `1.5.8` to `1.7.12`
and also I found some duplicated `SLF4J` packages should be removed from the `pom.xml` jars because of this error :

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.

also I have this error in the console while starting tomcat:

> INFOS: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath

this a problem in `servlet-api`, I am using the version `2.5` so to solve it I changed to the version `3.0.1`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and all problems is gone and spring logging is working fine :D