# Can`t configure spring cloud with log4j2

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, log4j2

I want to use log4j2 with spring cloud and spring boot so I checked the documentation here: [Logging](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html)

So i rewrited my pom:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ar.com.boldt</groupId>
            <artifactId>BGSCommons</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1b</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

So I created the config file like these one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="MyFile" fileName="logs/app.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And I leave it in src/main/resources but my config file, is never readed.
I miss something in the configuration?

Comment: What is the name of your file ? it should be named `log4j2.xml`. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Comment: try to check compatibily version log4j and slf4j with spring framework, may this link will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731846/cant-enable-logging-of-spring-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POM is missing entries for log4j-api and log4j-core. If your app uses the slf4j API, you also need to include the log4j-slf4j-impl dependency.