# How to tell spring to use log4j2 to print log messages?

Tags: java, spring, log4j2

when i use Spring to create beans and stuff, spring is using his apache commons logging (i guess) to print informations.

[image]

I want this information to be in a different color. Only my errors should be red but information like this should be green. So i heard you can only configure this if u use a different logger where you can add your own config file like log4j2. I tried following code to tell log4j2 to log spring messages but it didn't work out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="MyFile" fileName="all.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
        </Root>
        <logger name="org.springframework.beans">
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </logger>   
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

As the output is the same, i guess spring is not using log4j2. The first line you see I printed myself using

log.info("spring1 - property initialization");

Is there a way to completly log with log4j2? In the end, I just want these colors changed so maybe there is also a simpler way without log4j?

EDIT: I am using Spring boot and did not configure anything myself concerning spring.

Comment: Use LogBack instead of log4j2. Maybe you could provide more information on your spring configuration. Are you using SpringBoot?

Comment: exclude the common-logging jar and use jcl-over-slf4j which will use whatever supported logging framework found on classpath.

Comment: hope this answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30745022/2387708

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could

1. Setup you project to work with slf4j + log4j2
2. Exclude commons-logging from spring dependency and other deps
3. Add jcl-over-slf4j dependency to project

This will make Spring work thru commons-logging implementation pointing to slf4j, pointing to log4j2.